# how to convert sentence that contains "no more than 3" into predicate logic sentence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

How to convert sentence that contains “no more than 3” into predicate logic sentence?

For example: "No more than three $x$ satisfy $R(x)$"
using predicate logic.

This is what I have for "exactly one $x$ satisfies $R(x)$":
$\exists x(R(x) \land \forall y(R(y) \rightarrow (x = y)))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall u ((R(x)\wedge R(y) \wedge R(z) \wedge R(u)) \rightarrow (x=y \vee x=z \vee x=u \vee y=z \vee y=u \vee z=u))
$$

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting 'no more than three' as 'at most three' (i.e. it could be three, two, one, or maybe just none at all), you can do:

$$\exists x \exists y \exists z \forall u (R(u) \rightarrow (u = x \lor u = y \lor u = z))$$

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity in the question. What else could 'no more than three' mean?

Comment: @bof I agree, but the OP's inclusion of the 'exactly one' made me nervous that maybe the OP meant 'three, but no more', hence my explanation that I went with 'at most three'